# Python: Create new binary list based on some condition between two pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to compare two lists, one of a series of known values and the other a series of predictions from a classifier, and create a new binary list on whether the two elements were "close enough".

I will be using RMSE as a measure of fitness and if the difference between the predicted value and known value is less than say 1, I would like to put a 1 in this location of the new list, and if the error is greater than 1, return a 0 at this point in the new list.

For example:

```
y_known = {23,45,67,83}
y_pred = {23,46,64,78}
```

Should return

```
binary_array = [1,1,0,0]
```

I need this to calculate the precision / recall curve of my trained system. I have looked at using lambda expressions but apparently for this type of problem it is more hassle than it is worth. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This works flawlessly and did exactly what I needed it to. Original author withdrew his comment but thanks a lot!

```
def createBinaryArray(x, y, k):
    assert(len(x) == len(y))
    return([1 if abs(a-b)<=k else 0 for a,b in zip(x, y)])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
(np.abs(y_known - y_pred) <= 1).astype(int)
```

With your example input:

```
In [265]: y_known = np.array([23, 45, 67, 83])

In [266]: y_pred = np.array([23, 46, 64, 78])

In [267]: (np.abs(y_known - y_pred) <= 1).astype(int)
Out[267]: array([1, 1, 0, 0])
```

**Edit**, based on the comments: The same approach works just the same if what you start out with are pandas Series:

```
In [273]: y_known = pd.Series([23, 45, 67, 83])

In [274]: y_pred = pd.Series([23, 46, 64, 78])

In [278]: ((y_known - y_pred).abs() <= 1).astype(int)
Out[278]:
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Im using pandas Series object to contain data so I would prefer not to have to convert to a numpy object just to do this. The user withdrew his comment but I found that this function does the trick perfectly. Changes in OP.

Comment: The same approach works just the same for `pd.Series`; I've updated the answer accordingly.